# Invoke a function when the program is terminated or pc shutdown

Tags: python, python-2.7

my problem is that;

I want to invoke a function when the program is terminated or computer shutdowned.

I did search on the net , I found  atexit, here a sample program to tell what I want clearly

```
import atexit
a = 1
b = 0
while a==1:
    b += 1
    #if b=30: 
        #a=2
def say_bye():
    print " Goodbye "

atexit.register(say_bye)
```

it works if recomment the comment section, but it is not that I want. it prints "Goodbye" when all code are executed not when terminated or pc shutdown.

I hope it is clear, thanks in advance.

Python 2.7
Win 8 64

Comment: Why don't you register *before* the loop starts?

Comment: it does not change anything.:S (I tried to be sure)

Answer (score 4):

Note that `atexit` functions are not called when the program is interrupted, only when it finishes normally. More specifically, from the doc:

> Functions thus registered are automatically executed upon normal
>   interpreter termination.

You need to catch the proper signal with the `signal` module

```
$ cat t.py 
import signal


def say_bye(signum, frame):
    print " Goodbye "
    exit(1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, say_bye)

a = 1
b = 0
while a==1:
    b += 1
```

This program starts an infinite loop, but it has registered a signal handler for SIGINT, the signal which is sent when the user hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

```
$ python t.py 
^C Goodbye 
$
```

Note that without the `exit(1)` command, the program would not be terminated by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
$ python t.py
^C Goodbye 
^C Goodbye 
^C Goodbye 
^C Goodbye 
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 python t.py
```

I needed here to send another signal (SIGSTOP) to stop it.

After I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the Goodby message is displayed. You can do the same with SIGTERM, the signal sent with the `kill` command:

```
$ cat t.py 
import signal


def say_bye(signum, frame):
    print " Goodbye "
    exit(1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, say_bye)

a = 1
b = 0
while a==1:
    b += 1
```

The above codes gives:

```
$ python t.py & PID=$! ; sleep 1 && kill $PID
[1] 94883
 Goodbye 
[1]+  Exit 1                  python t.py
francois@macdam:~ $
```

Comment: Hum, just noted the small 'Win 8 64' at the end of the question. I just tested that on Linux but it should work in a similar fashion with Windows

Comment: it works only  with ctrl+C ? , I mean , I run a program then shutdown pc. does it still work?

Comment: You'll need to try it as I do not have access to a Win 8 computer.  But, as the second part of my answer indicates, you simply need to catch the correct signal to run the function when the computer is shut down.

Comment: But it does not work I expected. I don't know maybe it is imposibble :(